# Using python unittest.mock how can I mock an object coming from an external library created inside one of my libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-mock

I'm creating some test for my python project but I have a problem creating a unittest.patch

my_project.py

```
from service.my_service import Service
  
def main():
    token = '123456'
    my_service = Service(token)

    # calls to my service
```

service/my_service.py

```
from external_library import Client

class Service:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.__client = Client(token)

    #Methods that interacts with self.__client (the one I want to mock)
```

I would like to test the main() function mocking only the external_library.Client
To do so I created this test:
test/test_main

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch('my_project.Service.Client') 
def test_main(client_mock):
    ...
    main()
```

But it fails when it tries to patch saying that service/my_service/Service does not have the attribute 'Client'.
What is the issue and how can I mock this Client object?

Comment: you can't do that since `my_project.py` has no notion of `Client`. if you want to test `Client` then do so in `my_service.py`

Comment: You can't do that. By the time you get `Service` from `my_service` it's already got a reference to the original `Client`, and it's _not_ as an attribute of the class. If you want to test `main` with a real `Service` but a test double `Client`, invert the dependency so `Service` receives the `Client` instance rather than just the `token` with which to make one.

Comment: You mock the wrong object, check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). You need to `@patch('service.my_service.Client')`, and will get the created client from `client_mock.return_value`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Thanks, you pointed me to the right direction, the name reference mechanism was what I was missing. Many things make more sense now